# How to access a slider's value outside of it's function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, slider

I'm sure it's simple but I'm not getting it, this function works fine to display the slider's value (sales price), however I need to access it again in the button method below but can't pass the salesPrice value in?

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {




var salesPrice: Int?






@IBOutlet weak var salesPriceLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func salesPriceSlider(sender: UISlider) {
    salesPrice = roundUp(Int(sender.value), divisor: 1000)
    salesPriceLabel.text = "\(salesPrice!)"
}




@IBAction func testButton(sender: UIButton) {

                totalClosingCosts.text = "\(salesPrice!)"
```

returns nil

Comment: does the `salesPriceLabel.text` update? And if at all possible you should try to avoid using `!` use a `if let` statement instead to check if the salesPrice is not nil, your current method could result in a crash if you press the button and the slider value has not been set. Lastly what exactly returns nil?

Comment: @milo526 I think it works because the slider's value is initially the default value in attributes inspector until changed by the user

Comment: You where using a custom value `salesPrice` which is a `Int?` thus it’s an optional, you did not initialize it so it’s value is `nil` if you slide the slider you set the value to your `salesPrice` this will make it so your `testButton` will be able to read the `salesPrice`. The method in the answers do indeed ask for a value directly from the `UISlider` instead of using a custom variable. If you would (but you should’t!) use `var salesPrice: Int = salesPriceSlider.value` it will also work, than you could use `salesPrice` instead of the `salesPriceSlider.value`

Comment: Thanks @milo526 I think what I will do is initialize: salesPrice = Int?(200000) so that the default value of the slider matches.

Comment: Although you are of course free to day what you want, I would like to advice against it. If you can get the value do it. You can safely get the value from an `@IBOutlet` why not use it? What happens if you ever want to change the value of the slider in your storyboard (its initial value)? Certainly casting this as a `Int?` isn’t a good idea to use here. Why would you want to be able to set this value to nil? Your slider will always have a value if it is changed, if you set an initial value it is impossible to get it to `nil` unless you set it.

Comment: Using a static initializer here is in a sense programming against [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).

Comment: @milo526 I'm a newb so am learning on the fly.  I think I saw someone use optionals to initialize variables in a text field  and started doing it...perhaps it makes more sense there since there can be a value of nil in a textfield if nothing is typed?  as opposed to a slider that always has a value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75035/discussion-between-milo526-and-psu-sabes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a new referencing outlet (IBOutlet) to your slider (connect it to your view controller).

```
@IBOutlet weak var salesPriceSlider: UISlider!
```

[image]

to access is you just do it the same way

```
salesPriceLabel.text = salesPriceSlider.value.description
```

or

```
salesPriceLabel.text = roundUp(Int(salesPriceSlider.value), divisor: 1000).description
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make an `@IBOutlet` for your `UISlider`

```
@IBOutlet weak var salesPriceSlider: UISlider!
//Don’t forget to connect it to your storyboard!
```

After this you can use

```
salesPriceLabel.text = "\(salesPriceSlider.value)"
```

or as you use currently

```
salesPriceLabel.text = "\(roundUp(Int(salesPriceSlider.value), divisor: 1000))"
```

Comment: you can't assign a number to a text field

Comment: Obviously!  Appreciate it!

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus sorry same time so milo got it for a little more detail =)